# What word is more suitable than regret to describe the feeling of lamenting the fact that you will never have a particular experience?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, if I were to say "As a man, my greatest regret is that I will never be able to experience pregnancy or birth". It isn't an actual regret, because nothing has happened or could possibly happen, so it isn't a missed opportunity either per se.

Comment: Hello and welcome. It may be useful to describe what feelings you _are_ trying to describe, not just those that don’t fit. For example, is it just sadness you feel? In your question, talk about other terms you considered and why you set them aside. This gives the community a better idea of the concept you’re trying to distill into a single word.

Comment: Why not just say "I greatly lament the fact that . . ." (as this post's title suggests)?

Comment: Not one word, but, how about "wish in vain"? "I have been wishing in vain, to be able to experience..."

Comment: I am sorry that I will never…

Comment: There may be something better, but Merriam-Webster's first definition of [regret](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/regret) (noun) is "sorrow aroused by circumstances beyond one's control or power to repair" which certainly fits. "Regret" is commonly used when you are unable to do something.

Comment: I would suggest something like heartache,  heartbreak or heartsickness to describe similar but deeper feelings than simple regret, perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

One of your *lacks*, perhaps your greatest *lack*, is that you cannot experience pregnancy.

To say this is not to suggest that you regret it, nor that it is even possible: it is simply not available to you (in this case because you are male.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lack)
>
> Lack: noun
> the fact that something is not available or that there is not enough of it.

Merriam a Webster has similar definitions that support this argument.